# SQL Sum with Sub Query?

Tags: sql

Thanks for any help in advance, I can't wrap my SQL skills around this one...
I have two tables like this:

**Settings**

> **Customerid**     **ViewerLimit**
>          1                   50
>          2                   50

**Distribution**

> **Customerid**     **ServerIP**
>          1                 stream3
>          1                 stream4
>          2                 stream3

I want to calculate the load on each server.  A customer divides the load if they have more than one server, so here customer 1 puts a load of 25 on each server.  The result I'm trying to get is this:

> **ServerIP**      **Load**
>    stream3         75
>    stream4         25

I tried to do a sum function similar to this:

```
sum(viewerlimit/(count # of servers)) as load group by serverip
```

But I can't do a sub query within a sum function.  There are many customers and possibly many servers per customer so it will become too complex to do manually.  I appreciate any input.

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: I'm not sure how you get to 75 and 25 for the load. I'm missing a step...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is uninspired version with count in derived table:

```
select serverip, sum (viewerlimit/cast (ServerCount as float)) Load
from 
(
  select customerid, count(*) ServerCount from distribution group by customerid
) a
inner join settings
   on a.customerid = settings.customerid
inner join distribution 
   on settings.customerid = distribution.customerid
group by serverip
```

[Sql Fiddle to play around](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8f552/1)

**UPDATE - an attempt at explanation**

Derived tables are used to produce ad-hoc result sets that can be joined to main body of a query. It is placed in from clause and enclosed in parenthesis. You can use anything an ordinary select can use, top, order by, aggregate functions etc. The only thing you cannot use is correlation to a table in main body. Oh, and CTE. Derived table must be aliased.

In previous sample derived table 'a' selects counts of servers by customerid. Main body sees it as a table with CustomerId and ServerCount columns, ready to be used as any column from all listed tables. A join on customerid is performed between settings and 'a'. As this is 1:1 relation (both tables produce single row given a customerid), no duplication occurs.

Comment: Nice coding. I came up with a solution using CTE.

Comment: Wow, I can't honestly say I follow this even looking at it now, but it works!  Thanks, you're The Man!

Comment: @gbusman I've tried to explain things a bit. Hope you can pass by my broken english :-)

Comment: Thank you, that was very helpful, that and discovering that you don't need "as" to create an alias.  Your english is great, your SQL skills are greater :)

Comment: So you cannot do a SUM(SELECT... ) in any way? It has to be from a derived table?

Answer (score 1):

How about doing a count of servers in a sub query and assign that to a query variable and then use that query variable inside the sum function?

Answer (score 1):

```
select d.serverip, sum(s.viewerlimit/d.devider)
    from (
    select customerid, serverip, COUNT(serverip) over (partition by customerid) servercount
        from distribution
    ) d
    join settings s
        on s.customerid=d.customerid
    group by d.serverip
```