# SQL Sum sub-query with joined tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I have a forum site with posts (gems) and file attachments (gemdetail) along with replies (gems) to the posts and the replies can also have file attachments (gemdetail). Since both posts and replies are stored in the same table, it makes for an interesting left join which selects all posts with associated replies and detail.

I want to add another table to the mix (rating) which allows the user to rate each post. I then want to be able in the same query to get the sum total rating for each post. How to add sum(rating) so each row of the output will have the sum for the gemid. I know I need a sum sub-query (derived table w/ ad-hoc result sets) similar to the one found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9985674/sql-sum-with-sub-query), but it is above my skill set. Thanks in advance.

The table structure is as follows

```
table: gems
gemid    title        replygemid
-----    -----        ----------
220      map              NULL
223      inhabitants      NULL
403      reply to map     220

table: gemdetail
gemid    filename
------   --------
220      uganda-map.jpg
220      mozambique-map.jpg
223      uganda-inhabitants.jpg
223      kenya-inhabitants.jpg
403      mona-lisa-x8.jpg 

table: rating (to be added)
gemid    rating
-----    -------
220       1
220       5
223       3
403      -1
```

My current (simplified) query

```
SELECT g.gemid as ggemid, g.title as gtitle, gemdetail.filename as gfilename, r.filename as rfilename
FROM (SELECT gems.* FROM gems ) g 
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT title, x.gemid, x.replygemid, x.userid, y.filename  from gems x 
LEFT JOIN gemdetail y ON x.gemid = y.gemid ) r ON g.gemid = r.replygemid 
LEFT JOIN gemdetail ON g.gemid = gemdetail.gemid
```

Results may look like this

```
ggemid   replygemid gtitle          gfilename                   rfilename
------   ---------- ------          ---------------------       ----------------
220      403        Map             uganda-map.jpg              mona-lisa-x8.jpg
220      403        Map             mozambique-map.jpg          mona-lisa-x8.jpg
223      NULL       Inhabitants     uganda-inhabitants.jpg      NULL
223      NULL       Inhabitants     kenya-inhabitants.jpg       NULL
223      NULL       Inhabitants     kenya-inhabitants.jpg       NULL
```

Comment: What do you want the results to look like with the summing of rating added?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
SELECT g.gemid as ggemid, g.title as gtitle, gemdetail.filename as gfilename, r.filename as rfilename, rt.sum_rating
FROM (SELECT gems.* FROM gems ) g 
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT title, x.gemid, x.replygemid, x.userid, y.filename  from gems x 
LEFT JOIN gemdetail y ON x.gemid = y.gemid ) r ON g.gemid = r.replygemid 
LEFT JOIN gemdetail ON g.gemid = gemdetail.gemid 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT gemid, SUM(rating) as sum_rating from rating GROUP BY gemid) rt ON g.gemid = rt.gemid
```

Comment: Thank you for the a working answer. It is the simplest and most straight forward to work with what I have. As my query involves many more tables, it was a simple plug and play. Simpler than I thought. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c81e1/4)

**Query**:

```
SELECT g.gemid as ggemid, g2.gemid as replygemid, 
       g.title as gtitle, gd.filename as gfilename, 
       gd2.filename as rfilename, SUM(rating) as rating
FROM gems g
INNER JOIN gemdetail gd ON g.gemid = gd.gemid
INNER JOIN rating r ON g.gemid = r.gemid
LEFT OUTER JOIN gems g2 ON g.gemid = g2.replygemid
LEFT OUTER JOIN gemdetail gd2 ON g2.gemid = gd2.gemid
GROUP BY g.gemid, g2.gemid, g.title, 
         gd.filename, gd2.filename
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c81e1/4/0)**:

```
| GGEMID | REPLYGEMID |       GTITLE |              GFILENAME |        RFILENAME | RATING |
|--------|------------|--------------|------------------------|------------------|--------|
|    220 |        403 |          map |     mozambique-map.jpg | mona-lisa-x8.jpg |      6 |
|    220 |        403 |          map |         uganda-map.jpg | mona-lisa-x8.jpg |      6 |
|    223 |     (null) |  inhabitants |  kenya-inhabitants.jpg |           (null) |      3 |
|    223 |     (null) |  inhabitants | uganda-inhabitants.jpg |           (null) |      3 |
|    403 |     (null) | reply to map |       mona-lisa-x8.jpg |           (null) |     -1 |
```

Comment: I learned a lot from your answer (which works of course). I didn't know sql Fiddle existed. I learned more about grouping. And you did an admirable job cleaning up my nomenclature. In order to get it to work, I had to revert to Left Joins as all links don't exist. I appreciate immensely the time you put into making the Fiddle and getting this to work.